# Setting Properties a Control in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, custom-controls

I am creating a custom WPF control that uses an image inside of it.  This custom control will be like any other, it will be declared in xaml.  I want to have a public property for this control to specify the source of the internal image, much the same way you do this when using an Image control:

```
<Image Source="http://foo.com/bar.jpg"></Image>
```

What I want to do is have the following usage of my control:

```
<MyCustomControl ImageSource="http://foo.com/bar.jpg"></MyCustomControl>
```

And then internally, something like:

```
<UserControl class="MyCustomControl" ...>
     <Image Source="{Binding Imagesource}"></Image>
</UserControl>
```

What kind of setup do I need in my codebehind to get this to work?  i've tried a few things but can get nothing to work.

Comment: Are you asking how to create the 'ImageSource'?  If so you're looking for a DependencyProperty.  Or are you asking how to link the DependencyProperty to an encapsulated control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a [dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) of type `ImageSource` and a proper binding, either use [`ElementName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx) or [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource.aspx), do not use the `DataContext` on `UserControls`.

```
<UserControl Name="control" x:Class="MyCustomControl" ...>
     <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource, ElementName=control}"/>
</UserControl>

<UserControl x:Class="MyCustomControl" ...>
     <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource,
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: just out of curiosity - what's wring with using DataContext with user controls?

Comment: @Dmitry: You usually expect a DataContext to be inherited unless set explicitly, the problem is that when the DataContext is set in the UserControl it is *not even visible* on the instance and bindings will unexpectedly fail as a different DataContext was expected.

Comment: Oddly enough, this worked in my silverlight application, but not my WPF application.  Any idea why?

Comment: @PhilBrown: No, for the most part Silverlight is a subset of WPF, so that is odd. I do not know your exact code so it's really hard to tell.

Comment: I didn't have it added as a property.